# Order by date in mysql not displaying results with today's date

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

I have the following code to order results based on date closest to todays and including todays. The problem im having is that events with todays date are not displaying.

All the other dates are displaying in order

Heres my code:

```
"SELECT * FROM event WHERE `status` = 'open' AND event_date >= NOW() ORDER BY event_date"
```

Many thanks

Comment: Can you talk about table schema and show sample data?

Comment: Now probably includes timestamp, you'll need to extract just date portion or use date() if mysql supports it such as `curdate()`;

Comment: `now()` includes time data. If `event_date` is something like `2014-06-16 08:00:00`, and now() comes out to `2014-06-16 10:11:12`, you've excluded that "earlier today" event. maybe you want `curdate()` instead, which is just `yyyy-mm-dd`

Comment: curdate() does the trick, many thanks @MarcB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO the answer is...

```
SELECT * 
FROM event 
WHERE `status` = 'open' 
 AND event_date >= curdate() 
ORDER BY event_date
```

Reason as stated by Marc B and xQbert:

Now() includes time.  To get all records for today you have to use something that has midnight as the starting value which `curdate()` does.  Alternatively you could convert the now() to a value without time but that has overhead.  `curdate()` seems to meet the need.